# Take snapshot of MutableStateFlow that doesn't change with the state in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make an editor app that allows you to undo/redo changes. I want to achieve that by storing the ui state in stacks (`ArrayDeque`) and pop them back once the user hits undo/redo. But every time I stored the state in stack, after I made change to the state, the value in the stack is changed as well.

Is there a way to snapshot a state that won't be affected by future changes in the state flow?

My code looks something like this:

**Data Class**

```kt
class Data () {
    var number: Int = 0
    fun foo()
}
```

**State Class**

```kt
data class UiState(
    val dataList: MutableList<Data> = mutableListOf(),
)
```

**ViewModel**

```kt
class UiViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState())
    private val undoStack: ArrayDeque<UiState> = ArrayDeque()

    fun makeChangeToState() {
        saveStateToUndoStack(_uiState.value)

        Log.i("Test", undoStack.last().dataList[0].number) // 0

        val dataList= _uiState.value.dataList.toMutableStateList()
        dataList[0].number = 1
        _uiState.update { currentState ->
            currentState.copy(
                dataList = dataList,
            )
        }
        Log.i("Test", undoStack.last().dataList[0].number) // 1 because the _uiState changed
    }

    fun undo() {
        val lastState = undoStack.last()
        
        // Won't work because the data in lastState has already been updated with _uiState
        _uiState.update { lastState }
    }
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Use `_uiState.value.copy`
- Call `saveStateToUndoStack(uiState: UiState)` from Composable functions and pass in the `viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()`

Both doesn't seem to work, I play around for a few hours but don't have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the old value got updated is because all the objects in the list are references, not related to `MutableStateFlow`. I just need a deep copy of the list, see this post here:
https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/deep-copy-data-class

Another thread worth reading: [Deep copy of list with objects in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480079/deep-copy-of-list-with-objects-in-kotlin)