# Kotlin: ArrayList<Object> storing variables as values instead of reference

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I'm having an issue where I assign a variable based on data that is being received from a server (in JSON). 
I have two class variables

1. teams - which will be changed based on user interaction
2. reset_teams - which should always stay the same as the original list so that a user can reset all values whenever they choose.

These variables are used to (re-)populate a RecyclerView at various times based on user interaction (i.e., pressing a button inside of the app)

My problem is that **any time I make a change to an object in the *teams* ArrayList, it also makes a change to the *reset_teams* ArrayList**, as if they are somehow connected (similar to pass by value/reference in a function).

I am somewhat new to Kotlin, so it's quite possible I am missing something, but I'm wondering how I can keep the reset_teams ArrayList exactly the same at all times, even if the teams ArrayList has changes to different properties of the objects it stores?

```
// Class variables
var teams: ArrayList<myObject> = ArrayList()
var reset_teams: ArrayList<myObject> = ArrayList()

// Function to handle JSON after receiving data from remote server
private fun handleJson(jsonString: String?) {
    val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonString)

    val list = ArrayList<myObject>()

    var x = 0

    while (x < jsonArray.length()) {
        val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x)


        list.add(
            myObject(// a bunch of code to make an object of type myObject)
        )
        x++
    }

    teams = list
    reset_teams = list

    test()  // Change a property
}


private fun test(){
    teams[0].someProperty = 10
    println(teams)      // The someProperty of the first element of the ArrayList has been correctly assigned to 10
    println(reset_teams) // The someProperty of the first element of the ArrayList has been changed to 10 even though the reset_teams was never assigned a new value
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning

```
teams = list
reset_teams = list
```

both list `teams` and list `reset_teams` reference the same list (space) in memory (heap). With `teams[0].someProperty = 10` you change `someProperty` of the first element of this referenced list to 10. Since reset_teams references the same list, it also shows the changes.

In order to fix this unintended behaviour you will have to add copies of the objects to both lists `teams` and `reset_teams`. If class `myObject` is a data class, then you can add a copy by calling `teams.add(m.copy())` where `m` is an instance of class `myObject`.

*Remarks:*

- use camelCase for variable names: `resetTeams` instead of `reset_teams`
- start class names with a capital letter: `MyObject` instead of `myObject`
- prefer immutable objects if possible

Comment: Thanks for your comment Michael. That makes sense to me and I understand why the reference to the same memory is causing the issue. Can you explain to me how to 'add copies of the objects to both lists'?  I tried setting teams = ArrayList(list) and reset_teams = ArrayList(list) both this does not fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, that ought to fix the problem…  Can you double-check?  A similar alternative: `teams.clear(); teams.addAll(list); reset_teams.clear(); reset_teams.addAll(list)`.  (You could then make their references `val`s.  Or if you create new lists, you could make their references `List<myObject>`, i.e. nullable and immutable.  In general, I find it's often a code smell to have a mutable list with a mutable reference.)

Comment: By the way, it's conventional to use camelCase, not snake_case, for identifiers in Kotlin: `resetTeams` instead of `reset_teams`.  And PascalCase for classes and object types: `MyObject` instead of `myObject`.  (That won't affect how it runs, of course, but would make it slightly easier for idiots like me to follow!)

Comment: Thanks for the Kotlin conventions. I will adhere to that moving forward. For consistency's sake in this thread I will continue using the original that I posted. It is strange, even if I: teams.clear();
        teams.addAll(list);
        reset_teams.clear();
        reset_teams.addAll(list);
        teams[0].someProperty = 99
        println(reset_teams)
        println(teams)   both lists are exactly the same. They are also declared as 'val'

Comment: I created a bit of a workaround that does work, but it unfortunately doesn't really solve the problem. Oh well, c'est la vie

Comment: if class `myObject` is a data class then you can simply call `.copy()` on an instance in order to place a copy in your list. Besides I totally agree with @gidds remarks!

Comment: Ah!  Light dawns.  I suspect what's happening is that you're now creating a completely new list each time — but that list references the same `myObject` instances as the original.  So if you change the state of a `myObject` instance via one list, it'll be visible through the others.  (Hard to be sure without seeing the code for `myObject`, but seems very likely.)  If so, what you need is a ‘deep copy’ of the list, one that creates new `myObject` instances (replicating the state of the originals)… (contd)

Comment: …As Michael Kreutz says, calling `copy()` (if available) goes part-way toward that, but it's not a full solution: if `myObject` contains any references to _other_ objects, `copy()` would simply copy _those_ references.  A proper deep copy isn't easy; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359496/kotlin-data-class-copy-method-not-deep-copying-all-members). You may need to rethink your approach with that in mind.